# Subscript out of bounds for reverse geocoding loop in R

Tags: r, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am attempting to reverse geocode a data-set using the google api key. I managed to run the code and get the desired results for a small sample of 10, but it gives an error

```
Error in rgc$results[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I managed to integrate the api key by using the following code:

```
` revgx <- mapply(function(latlng, api_key){


url= paste("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?","latlng=",latlng,"&key=",sep="")

rgc <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(url), collapse = ''))

rgc <- rgc$results[[1]]


with(rgc,{rgcdf <<- data.frame(
address = formatted_address
)})
for(k in seq_along(rgc$address_components)){
rgcdf <- cbind(rgcdf, rgc$address_components[[k]]$long_name)
}
names(rgcdf) <- c('address', sapply(rgc$address_components, function(l)     l$types[1]))

# return 'more' output
rgcdf
},
y1$latlng)`
```

I tried using the same with incorporating xml too, but to no avail. Please suggest if any changes are required to be made to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and it's working for me. But you aren't testing for status. If latlng is incorrect, it return "ZERO RESULTS" as status (and no rgc$results exist). Here's the code that I tested.

```
rev <- function(latlng, api_key) {

url= url(paste("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?","latlng=",latlng,"&key=",sep=""))
rgc <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(url), collapse = ''))
close(url)

if (rgc["status"] == "OK") {
    rgc <- rgc$results[[1]]
    with(rgc, {
        rgcdf <<- data.frame(address = formatted_address)
    })
    for (k in seq_along(rgc$address_components)) {
        rgcdf <- cbind(rgcdf, rgc$address_components[[k]]$long_name)
    }
    names(rgcdf) <- c("address", sapply(rgc$address_components, function(l) l$types[1]))
    rgcdf["valid_latlong"] <- TRUE
    rgcdf
} else {
    rgcdf <- c(valid_latlong=FALSE)
}
}
```

I tested this with:

```
rev("12.9756300,77.6066230")
```

Are you passing latlng in this format? Or c(9756300,77.6066230) . Then you need to do

```
latlng <-  gsub(' ','%20', paste(latlng, collapse=","))
```

Also you haven't integrated api key in the code snippet that you shared. Pass api_key to query param.

Comment: Thank you @khrm!! I ran the code and it workd pretty accurately. However, when I pass 60 queries, it gives me a list of 60 to start with. Then, I use the code `df1 <- rbindlist(df, fill= TRUE)` to bind this list. This deleted 5 results from the list of 60 and hence I could not `cbind` with the original dataset to get a database of lat,lng, and the address fields. I get the error `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 60, 55`

Comment: I added valid_latlong. Now you should be able to use cbind. If this helps accept and upvote.

Comment: Thanks @ khrm. The list obtained can be bound in the following manner `list = rbindlist(lapply(dflist, as.data.table), fill = TRUE)` and can be bound with the dataframe of lat-lng by `df1 <-  cbind(df, list)`

Comment: The code gives the following error when run for a larger set of queries (150 queries) `Error in fromJSON(paste(readLines(url), collapse = "")) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'content' in selecting a method for function 'fromJSON': Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection`

Comment: You should close connection. Will modify the code. Currently in office.

Comment: OK.I have modified the code. Close the connection and try this code.

Comment: I have tested the code for two sets of 2500 queries. It does seem to work accurately.@khrm, many thanks!!!